# There exists a function satisfying these $3$ properties?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, examples-counterexamples

I am trying to find an example of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ such that:

1. $f$ is bounded;
2. $\displaystyle\lim_{|x|\to \infty} f(x)=0$;
3. its gradient satisfies $-\nabla f(x) = \alpha x$,
   with $\alpha=\alpha(|x|)$ is a constant related to $|x|$ and/or its powers (I mean e.g $\alpha=|x|^{-3}$).

I was thinking about
$$f(x) = -|x|^{-1},$$
but unfortunately it is not bounded.

Could someone please help me in finding an example of function like that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what $\alpha $ is meant to be.  Is it a constant?  Is it a function of $x$?  Anyway, why not just take $f(x)$ to be the constant $0$?

Comment: $f(x)=e^{-|x|^2}$ has $\nabla f(x)=-2e^{-|x|^2}x$. It is $C^{\infty}$, and derivatives of all order vanish at infinity.